# Periodically run script in Crontab to open and close firefox

Tags: linux, shell, cron, raspberry-pi

I would like to periodically run a script which opens firefox and afterwards closes firefox.

**Crontab**

```
* * * * * su pi -c "/home/pi/Desktop/launcher.sh"
```

**Launcher.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
    
pkill firefox
su pi -c "DISPLAY=:0.0; /usr/bin/firefox --new-window http://www.cyberciti.com"
```

It seems that there is a syntax error because firefox will not be opened!

I tried to open firefox immediately in Crontab like this:

```
* * * * * su pi -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/firefox -new-window www.google.de"
```

This works but is not what I try to do.

Comment: Maybe the `$PATH` isn't what you expect. Have you tried to use full, absolute paths for all commands?

Comment: Checkout https://askubuntu.com/q/514167/84290 this is similar to your problem, maybe there are some hints

Comment: PATH should be correct, when I delete 'su pi -c "DISPLAY=:0.0;' It works if i run the script immediately and not via crontab

Comment: Yeah but the environment in the shell cron uses might be different. But it's just a guess from my side. I don't *know* it. I thought it might be worth a try though.

Comment: Either `export DISPLAY=:0.0; /usr/bin/firefox...` (2 statements) or `DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/firefox...` (1 statement with no semi-colon)

Comment: Does the script work outside cron?